# Thymeleaf not sending object to controller from html where html element is being created Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've got an HTML element which is being created through JavaScript.
I've enter Thymeleaf object in the same html element. Here's my js Code :-

```
$("#subcategoryNameDiv").append(''+
                         '<div class="form-group margindate">'+
                        '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 datesubscription nowrap">Category Name:</label>'+
                         '<div class="col-sm-9 ">'+
                             '<select id="categorySelect" th:field="${category}" class="date_dropdown date_input form-control" onchange="loadSubcategories()">'+
                             '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+
                     '</div>'+
                       '<div class="form-group margindate" >'+
                        '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 datesubscription nowrap">Subcategory Name:</label>'+
                         '<div class="col-sm-9 ">'+
                            '<select id="subcategorySelect" th:field="*{subcategory}" class="date_dropdown date_input form-control" required>'+
                             '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+
                     '</div>');
```

Thymeleaf is working properly while creating normal HTML element and sending Object to Controller but as per our Project's requirement this element is being generated when a specific option is Selected.

**NOTE -  Here, loadSubcategories() function is working properly and appending values to HTML element id="subcategorySelect". But after Submit "catgory" & "Subcategory" values are null on Spring Boot Controller.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to process this html in the server side and then append using jquery.

Url to get data using ajax

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
private ResponseBody test( HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse )
{
    Response response = new Response<String>();
    WebContext webContext = new WebContext( httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, servletContext );



    response.setData( generateTemplate( webContext, viewResolver, "pathTohtmlSection") );
    response.setMessage( "Success" );
    response.setStatus(SUCCESS );

    return response;

}
```

Generate html as a string

```
  public static String generateTemplate( WebContext ctx, ViewResolver viewResolver, String baseTemplate)
{

    TemplateEngine engine = ( ( ThymeleafViewResolver ) viewResolver ).getTemplateEngine();

    String renderedHtml = engine.process( baseTemplate, ctx );
    return renderedHtml;

}
```

Now use jquery as follow.

```
 $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "abc",
  data: data,
  success: function(response){
   $("#subcategoryNameDiv").html(response.data);
  };
});
```

Comment: Hello , Supun Thank you for responding, However, the I've got around 22-25 different elements which is being generated dynamically just like my question so in that case it'd quite difficult to get it resolve.
Is there any alternate to the problem.??
Also, I've done the same thing in JSP it was working fine in JSP.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the best solution. You can send multiple ajax request to render those elements.